# How to alternate map markers with jQuery click event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps

I am trying to show specific map markers when clicking an accordion element and hide the other markers if they exist.

I am building my markers with this:

```
function setMarkers(data) {

    var items, markers_data = [];

    if (data.length > 0) {
        items = data;
        j = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
            var item = items[i];
            j++
            lat_long = ('"' + item.martygeocoderlatlng + '"');
            lat_long = lat_long.replace(/\(|\)/g, '');
            lat_long = lat_long.split(',');

            lat = lat_long[0].replace('"', '');
            lng = lat_long[1].replace('"', '');

            marker_id = item.id;

            if (lat != undefined && lng != undefined) {
                var icon = 'community.png';

                markers_data.push({
                    lat: lat,
                    lng: lng,
                    id: marker_id,
                    title: item.title.rendered,
                    infoWindow: {
                        content: '<div class="infoWindow"><h3>' + item.title.rendered + '</h3>' + item.content.rendered + '<strong>Phone:</strong> <a target="_blank" href="tel:' + item.aoi_phone + '">' + item.aoi_phone + '</a><!--<br><strong>Hours:</strong> ' + item.aoi_hours + '--><br><a href="' + item.aoi_url + '">Visit Website</a></div>'
                    },
                    icon: {
                        url: '/wp-content/plugins/lstar-custom/assets/img/list_marker_' + j + ".png",
                        //anchor:new google.maps.Point(scaledSize/4,scaledSize/4),
                        size: new google.maps.Size(25, 25)
                    },
                    animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP,
                });
            }
        }
    }
    // console.log(markers_data);
    map.addMarkers(markers_data);

}
```

I am alternating the data passed to the setMarkers function with this:

```
jQuery('#poi_cat_amusementattractions').one('click', function(e) {
    var xhr_cat_amuse = jQuery.getJSON('path/to/json');
    xhr_cat_amuse.done(setMarkers);
});
jQuery('#poi_cat_dining').one('click', function(e) {
    var xhr_cat_dine = jQuery.getJSON('path/to/json');
    xhr_cat_dine.done(setMarkers);
});
```

Which works to bring the markers on the map, but how can I remove any existing markers when clicking the element?

I am also using this plugin for gmaps. 
https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/

Comment: The function `addMarkers` is not a [standard function](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers) of the google maps api, so if you wrote it yourself, or if you are using some library for that - it will be hard to help without knowing what exactly this function does.

Comment: @Dekel sorry I am using this tool, https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/

Comment: Did you see the answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library you mentioned in the comments have the [`removeMarkers` function](https://hpneo.github.io/gmaps/documentation.html#GMaps-removeMarkers) (clears all of the markers already added to the map).

You can call this function inside your `setMarkers` function, right before your call to `addMarkers`:

```
function setMarkers (data) {
    ...

    // Clear the map from all markers
    map.removeMarkers();

    // Add new markers to the map
    map.addMarkers(markers_data);
}
```